# Google Cloud SDK shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am using Google cloud SDK shell to upload files at gcloud by using 
-> "gcloud app deploy"
which is working fine so far with me, but issue it consume long time to deploy files.

So I want to know if there is any other quick away to upload the files. Something like FTP connection?

Comment: Do you want merely to move the file on the instance or to deploy the local code and/or configuration of your app to App Engine. Because this is what `gcloud deploy` does, this is why is "slow"

Comment: basically I want to move the file on the instance after making changes. Yes I also want my changes should reflect on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SFTP in you browser to upload files to your instances.

1 - If you have not yet applied a public key to your GCP Console project or instance, obtain an SSH key pair and apply the public SSH key file to your project or instance.

2 - Open a terminal and add an entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file that points to your private key. For this example, the private key file is `~/.ssh/my-ssh-key.`

3 - Open your file browser and establish a connection to your instance. Paste the combined username and IP address into your file browser: 
`sftp://[USERNAME]@[IP_ADDRESS]/home/[USERNAME]`

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#filebrowser

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to transfer files.  You can use google cloud sdk to do this from command line:

```
gcloud compute scp [LOCAL_FILE_PATH] [INSTANCE_NAME]:~/
```

Check this page for all the options and details: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#transfergcloud